# Regex to get the last occurence of "::" character

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I'm working with a third party library that concatenates a string with a double colon `::`. I need to split that string because the element on the right hand side is important to me, but the left doesn't matter.

ie

```
This is not what I want::what-i-want
```

Note: the text on the right hand side does not contain any `:` characters

I need to write a regex to get the text on the right hand side.

```
string.split(/::(.*)$/)
```

but this doesn't work because the text on the left hand side does can contain `:` characters

The regex needs to work for this case

```
var string = ":this:should:split::correctly:::and-return-this"
```

Comment: You want result is `and-return-this` or `correctly:::and-return-this` ?

Comment: Given that your answer to namgold's question is the latter option, you could do something like this: `let afterDubCol = str.replace(/^.*::(.*)$/, '$1');`

Comment: William, can you let us know if you are looking for the string after the last occurrence of `::` even if it has an extra `:` to return `and-return-this`(as the answers below are doing) or did you want it to ignore the `:::` and get the last occurrence of exactly `::` to return `correctly:::and-return-this`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
/::([^:]*)$/
```

Test on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/sRNZ1Q/1)

Comment: This won't work if there's a `:` in the part after the last `::`

Answer (score 1):

You could split on a double colon, and assert what is on the left and right is any char except a colon.

```
(?<=[^:])::(?=[^:])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/r0NA8d/1)

```js
let s = ":this:should:split::correctly:::and-return-this";
console.log(s.split(/(?<=[^:])::(?=[^:])/).pop());
```

If you also want to split when the `::` is either at the start or end of the string:

```
(?<!:)::(?!:)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nA6n9A/1)

Comment: I did consider using split as an option for my answer too, but it doesn't work well for the sample string in the question ":this:should:split::correctly:::and-return-this" - it includes the extra `:` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Regex or string functions:

**Regex:**

- To get the text after the ***first* occurrence of `::`** - use `::(.+)` - this will work even if the string starts with `::`
- To get the text after the ***last* occurrence of `::`** - use `^.*::(.*)` - this will work for strings with `:` after the last `::`, but it will return nothing if the last characters are `::`

```js
var string = ":this:should:split::correctly:::and-return-this";
var result = /::(.+)/.exec(string)[1];
console.log("After first occurrence = " + result);

var string = ":this:should:split::correctly:::and-return-this";
var result = /^.*::(.*)/.exec(string)[1];
console.log("After last occurrence = " + result);

var string = ":this:should:split::correctly:::and-return:this";
var result = /^.*::(.*)/.exec(string)[1];
console.log("Single : in last part = " + result);


var string = ":this:should:split::correctly:::and-return-this:";
var result = /^.*::(.*)/.exec(string)[1];
console.log("Ends with : = " + result);

var string = ":this:should:split::correctly:::and-return-this::";
var result = /^.*::(.*)/.exec(string)[1];
console.log("Ends with :: = " + result);

var string = "::this:should:split::correctly:::and-return-this";
var result = /^.*::(.*)/.exec(string)[1];
console.log("Starts with :: = " + result);
```

**String Functions:**

You can use `indexOf` / `lastIndexOf` to get the position of the `::` and then `slice` the string from that position to the end.

[indexOf documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) 
[lastIndexOf Dcoumentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) 
[Slice Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

```js
var string = ":this:should:split::correctly:::and-return-this";
var result = string.slice(string.indexOf('::') + 2, string.length);
console.log("After first occurrence = " + result);

result = string.slice(string.lastIndexOf('::') + 2, string.length);
console.log("After last occurrence = " + result);

var string = ":this:should:split::correctly:::and-return:this";
result = string.slice(string.lastIndexOf('::') + 2, string.length);
console.log("Single : in last part = " + result);

var string = ":this:should:split::correctly:::and-return-this:";
result = string.slice(string.lastIndexOf('::') + 2, string.length);
console.log("Ends with : = " + result);

var string = ":this:should:split::correctly:::and-return-this::";
result = string.slice(string.lastIndexOf('::') + 2, string.length);
console.log("Ends with :: = " + result);

var string = "::this:should:split::correctly:::and-return-this";
result = string.slice(string.indexOf('::') + 2, string.length);
console.log("Starts with :: = " + result);
```